# Memory allocation when creating new String as literal/new Object

Tags: java, string, string-literals

Code:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = new String("Hello");

Field declaredField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
declaredField.setAccessible(true);

byte[] arr1 = (byte[])declaredField.get(s1);
byte[] arr2 = (byte[])declaredField.get(s2);
```

Now, s1 == s2 = False, arr1== arr2 = True.

My question is how are the objects being stored in the memory.

First line does create a new String type object on the pool. Second line does create it on the heap as a regular object

But the underlying byte[] array is the same. This makes me think, somehow JVM does this check if such an existing byte[] already exists and points all references to the same array. Does this mean the underlying array is cached in the pool, no matter we use the literal or new keyword?

So s = "something" creates a new String type object on the pool along with a underlying array holding the data - which is also created on the pool.

`s = new String("something")` -> creates the String type object on the heap, but the underlying array still stored in the pool/if already exists, a reference is just created.

Is my understanding correct?

Note: this is not a question about where is the constant pool stored, how intern works, how many objects are created or how using a different creation technique/using intern affects the == results.

Comment: The JVM does not attempt to do "deduplication" of data.

Comment: @ch Didn't quite get your answer to the context, please can you be a little more elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What java version do you use? I check it on 11 jdk and type of String.value is char[]. All next words based on 11 JDK version.

The reason for this behavior is a String constructor.

```
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

As you can see, the `value` field is copied from `original` String object. Since you are using `"Hello"` for `new String(...)` argument, `"Hello"` is gotten from the String pool and passed to the constructor, where the `value` field is copping to a new String object.

You can change your code a bit for reaching expected behaviour:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = new String("Hell") + "o";
Field declaredField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
declaredField.setAccessible(true);
char[] arr1 = (char[])declaredField.get(s1);
char[] arr2 = (char[])declaredField.get(s2);
assert arr1 != arr2;
assert s1.equals(s2);
```

Comment: This actually makes sense now. Thanks for the tip. Never really thought of looking at the constructor :(

So basically, the first object to be created is in the pool-> The object passed in as original ? Then depending on literal/new keyword, JVM either allocates or doesnt a memory location on the general heap ?

Comment: Btw I am using Open jdk amazon-corretto 11. I have seen open jdk using byte[] and oracle using char[]. Ill have to some more research into this, I think this has something to with compaction - UTF-1 and Latin1 encoding. Will have to read more about this

Comment: I took another way to do a little research on this. I'll generate the bytecode and try to figure out more. I will post my understanding in as an answer later.